# How to do Loop to calculate the cell values in DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net

How to multiply a value of a `row` of a `column` to all the values in another `column` and do the loop for all `rows`.Then, at the end, sum the values in each `row`?

Here is an example.
Please note that I do not need to have or show these three columns (I, II, III). I just put them in there to show the steps.

Thanks a lot for your help!

[image: Example]

The loop works only for the 1st two rows in Column 3..!!?

```
Dim i As Integer
For k As Integer = 0 To Data1.ColumnCount - 4

For j = 0 to Data1.Rows.Count - 2

Data1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value = Data1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value * _
Data1.Rows(j).Cells(1).Value 


For i = 0 To EOF()

i = i + 1

Data1.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value = Data1.Rows(j).Cells(0).Value *_ 
Data1.Rows(k+i).Cells(1).Value + Data1.Rows(j).Cells(2).Value

Next i 
Next j
Next k
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this isn't how SO works. You need to have a _specific_ problem and you need to show us what you have tried so we can help you with that specific problem you have. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! The example table is the problem that I am trying to solve. I've added what I've done so far. The loop just works for the first two column (in C3). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution doesn't use a DataGridView (or GridView) but using arrays. The trick is creating a list of row, column and the multiplication result. See the table below to see how the list looks like. After the list is built, it's just grouping by the second value (row) and calculate the sum the third value.

```
Dim C1 = { 40, 30, 20, 10 } ' column C1
Dim C2 = { 1, 2, 3 }        ' column C2

' to store the result of multiplication between C1 and C2
' first value is Column, second value is Row, third column is the multiplication result
Dim list = New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer))

For i = 0 To C2.Length - 1
    For j = 0 To C1.Length - 1
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)( i, i + j, C2(i) * C1(j) )) ' column, row, value
    Next
Next

' to store sum of each row
' key is row, value is sum of the row
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

For Each row In list ' iterate each row in list
    If dict.ContainsKey(row.Item2) ' if dictionary contains row number
        dict(row.Item2) += row.Item3 ' add value to existing row
    Else
        dict.Add(row.Item2, row.Item3) ' add new row
    End If
Next

For Each entry In dict
    Console.WriteLine("Total Row {0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value)
Next
```

Alternative using LINQ to get the sum.

```
Dim C1 = { 40, 30, 20, 10 } ' column C1
Dim C2 = { 1, 2, 3 }        ' column C2

' to store the result of multiplication between C1 and C2
' first value is Column, second value is Row, third column is the multiplication result
Dim list = New List(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer))

For i = 0 To C2.Length - 1
    For j = 0 To C1.Length - 1
        list.Add(New Tuple(Of Integer, Integer, Integer)( i, i + j, C2(i) * C1(j) )) ' column, row, value
    Next
Next

' LINQ sum
Dim result = From l In list
             Group By l.Item2  ' group by row
             Into Sum(l.Item3) ' sum of value

For Each row In result
    Console.WriteLine("Total Row {0} = {1}", row.Item2, row.Sum)
Next
```

[image]

Spreadsheet version of the list with colored rows grouped by Row (2nd) column.
[image]

Result:

```
Total Row 0 = 40
Total Row 1 = 110
Total Row 2 = 200
Total Row 3 = 140
Total Row 4 = 80
Total Row 5 = 30
```

I hope you get the idea to implement this code in your project.

EDIT. Optimized solution with less looping.

```
Dim C1 = { 40, 30, 20, 10 } ' column C1
Dim C2 = { 1, 2, 3 }        ' column C2

Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

For i = 0 To C2.Length - 1
    For j = 0 To C1.Length - 1
        If dict.ContainsKey(i + j) ' if dictionary contains row number
            dict(i + j) += C2(i) * C1(j) ' add value to existing row
        Else
            dict.Add(i + j, C2(i) * C1(j)) ' add new row
        End If
    Next
Next

For Each entry In dict
    Console.WriteLine("Total Row {0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value)
Next
```

Sample in Windows Form application. Add a DataGridView and a Button into the form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadInitialData()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Calculate()
    End Sub

    Sub LoadInitialData()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(40, 1)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(30, 2)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(20, 3)
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(10, Nothing)
    End Sub

    Sub Calculate()

        Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                ' check if both are numbers
                If IsNumeric(DataGridView1(0, i).Value) And IsNumeric(DataGridView1(1, j).Value) Then
                    Dim C1 = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1(0, i).Value) ' value of C1 from 1st column of outer loop
                    Dim C2 = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1(1, j).Value) ' value of C2 from 2nd column of inner loop

                    If dict.ContainsKey(i + j) Then ' check if dictionary has entry
                        dict(i + j) += C1 * C2 ' increment the value in dictionary
                    Else
                        dict.Add(i + j, C1 * C2) ' add new entry into dictionary
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next

        For Each entry In dict
            ' check if row in datagridview is lesser than dictionary entries
            If DataGridView1.Rows.Count < dict.Keys.Count Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add() ' add empty row
            End If
            DataGridView1(2, entry.Key).Value = entry.Value ' set value in 3rd column
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks so much Han for the help and comments! this is awesome, really appreciate it....thanks so much again! :)

Comment: is this solution would be possible to be done using a DataGridView (or GridView) as well? I need to transfer the results into another DataGridView for my further calculation. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to transfer the result to a DataGridView, add a column, then set the value of the new column from the dictionary object.

Comment: I am  not good at coding and got confused...! Still I can not get this to work...! if there is a way that I can do this solution using DataGridView instead of using arrays that would be easier for me. It would be greatly appreciate if anyone can help me out here...! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added a winform sample.

Comment: Thanks so much Han...!! it is perfect, really appreciate your time... :)